# Polymorphic assocs but with inherited attribute names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have the following associations:

```
class ServCost < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :servitem, :polymorphic => true
end

class TourDet < ActiveRecord::Base
 has _many :serv_costs,  :as => servitem
end

class AdhocBkg < ActiveRecord::Base
 has _many :serv_costs,  :as => servitem
end
```

The only problem that I have is that the attribute names in ServCost are: servcostservitemid and servcostservitemtype and I have inherited those so I can't change them.  What are my options?

1. Can I do something like `:foreign_key => :servcostservitemid` ... but what about the 'type' field?
2. Some other way of achieving access to ServCost items from AdhocBkg and TourDet and vice versa?

I am using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.